# How do I do a drop-down list without duplicate elements?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a list of objects and multiple drop-downs. I want to display the data from the list.  But my problem is that I didn't want to have something like this:

For example: I don't want to have in drop-down a file name for two times :

```
file1
file1
file2
file3
file3
```

I want to have only: `file1, file2, file3`

This is my controller where I put the list in model

```
@GetMapping("/filter/functionality/misramessages")
public String filterFunctionality(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("misraMessages", misraMessagesService.findAllMisraMessagesFromDb());
    return "functionality";
}
```

And after in html I do this:

```html
 <!-- Filter File Name-->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="fileName" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">File Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control"  name="file_name" id="fileName">
                    <option th:value="0" text="Please Select"></option>
                    <option  th:each = "misra : ${misraMessages}"
                             th:value="${misra.fileName}"
                             th:text="${misra.fileName}">
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

<!-- Filter Message Number-->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="messageNumber" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Message Number</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control"  name="message_number" id="messageNumber">
                    <option th:value="0" text="Please Select"></option>
                    <option  th:each = "misra : ${misraMessages}"
                             th:value="${misra.messageNumber}"
                             th:text="${misra.messageNumber}">
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        .......
        .......
```

Comment: There are several ways to eliminate duplicates. You could even try to eliminate them in your database query, maybe using the `DISTINCT` keyword. You could as well eliminate them in the method `misraMessagesService.findAllMisraMessagesFromDb()` using Java. What do you prefer? How does the method look?

Comment: It is simple :
 @Override
    public List<MisraMessages> findAllMisraMessagesFromDb() {
        return misraMessagesRepository.findAll();
    }

Comment: Then have a look at the database query. You should be able to eliminate duplicates there. See the answers given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always better not to bring in duplicates to memory if that is causing issues and duplicate removal is needed.

So instead of using repository method - `misraMessagesRepository.findAll();` , you need to write a new method in that repository which returns `DISTINCT` results and use that method in DAO.

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM MESSAGES_TABLE" , nativeQuery = true)
List<MisraMessages> findDistinctMessages();
```

You haven't shown your repository so I used dummy table name. Show your repository code and Entity details if still confused and need better answer.

Comment: I did like you told me but I received this error : Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.cidashboard.repositories.MisraMessagesRepository.findDistinctMessages()!

Comment: I need to annotate the entity with @NamedNativeQuery(name = ...
) ?

Comment: @Alexandra : I updated answer with `nativeQuery = true` . Try that.

Answer (score 3):

Well I expect that `misraMessagesService.findAllMisraMessagesFromDb()` is returning list of String. So you can do something like this if you don't want to change your `findAllMisraMessagesFromDb()` method:

```
List<String> messages = misraMessagesService.findAllMisraMessagesFromDb();
Set<String> uniqueMsgs = new HashSet<String>(messages);
```

or you can also create a new method in `misraMessagesRepository`:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM MisraMessages")
public List<MisraMessages> findDistinctMisraMessagesFromDb();
```

either of the two will work.

Answer (score 2):

Never go for JAVA way to do the same because it is simply double processing time.

I would avoid processing in Java level code as it is easily possible by query level.

Just use **`Select distinct`** keyword and it works like a charm..!!

Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your List into Set. It will remove your duplicates then put into model.